# transaction sign from 2 different wallet to unknown wallet

Tags: cardano-cli, wallet, transaction, signing-key-file

i have 2 wallet in my node, each one hold different Asset and ADA.
i want to sign a transaction with "cardano-cli transaction sign" command, using 2 times the "--signing-key-file " option for the 2 different wallets .., and i want to send all this tokens and ada to an unknown wallet.

is it possible?

example,
wallet_1 = holds 10 ADA
wallet_2 = holds 100 Tokens

```
            cardano-cli transaction sign \
                --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath_A \
                --signing-key-file $paymentSignKeyPath_B \
                --tx-body-file ${txraw} \
                --out-file ${txsigned} \
                --mainnet >> $log
```

is that possible=? and also is it possible this one to be sent to an unknown 3rd wallet?

thank you,
TTS17

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible, as long as the raw transaction is properly built.

If you wish to consolidate all UTXOs in the two wallets into a single one on the third wallet, you'd use all the UTXOs as `--tx-in`, and have a single `--tx-out`. Also, make sure that when estimated the fee, indicate that there will be two witnesses.

Comment: yes , thank you. 
more specific to be,
i want from wallet-1 to send only NFT, from wallet_2 to send the minimum of the ada amount which must follow a NFT to a wallet_3, which wallet3 is unknown.